# Highlight row based on cell value in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a sheet with data in 3 columns.  Now I want to select all the rows that contain certain text in one of the specific columns, but that column contains multiple values per cell.

[image]

So in the above I want to highlight **all the rows** that in column C contain the text 'bbb'.  If I add a new conditional formatting rule with the formula =$C1="bbb" only the 4th row is selected.  How can I also have the 1st and 2nd rows selected please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF`.

As your conditional formula

```
=COUNTIF($C2,"*bbb*")
```

Then as your Applies To range

```
=$2:$200
```

or whatever you last row is, but the start row needs to be the same as the row referenced in your conditional formula.

You can also make `"*bbb*"` a reference to a cell so you could change it after the fact.  `=COUNTIF($C2,"*" & $A$1 & "*")`

[image]

Note that the column is locked in for the conditional formula (**$**C2) and the Applies to Range is the whole rows.

(Working when cell contents are more than just "bbb")

[image]

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks but using countif is only selecting the cells that contain "bbb" and I need to selec the whole row that contains "bbb" in column C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this conditional formatting rule:

`=IF(FIND("bbb",C1)>0,TRUE,FALSE)`

If "bbb" is found anywhere within `C1`, it will return a number greater than 0 and will return `TRUE`.

Comment: Hi dwirony, thanks but that helps me to highlight only the cells that have specifically "bbb", whilst I need to select the whole row that contains "bbb" in column C.

Comment: @Dragonfly I tested the function and it works. It works for any cell containing "bbb" inside. The `Find` function's purpose is to find "bbb" inside the cell, then you can apply it to the whole row as in the other answer

Comment: Ah you needed the whole row highlighted, I didn't realize that.